# Pythonic alternatives to if/else statements

Tags: python, optimization, if-statement, data-structures

I'm trying to avoid a complex web of if/elif/else statements.

What pythonic approaches can I use to accomplish my goal.

Here's what I want to achieve:

My script will receive a slew of different urls,

youtube.com, hulu.com, netflix.com, instagram.com, imgur.com, etc, etc possibly 1000s of different domains.

I will have a function/set of different instructions that will be called for each distinct site.

so....

```
    if urlParsed.netloc == "www.youtube.com":
        youtube()
    if urlParsed.netloc == "hulu.com":
        hulu()
    and so on for 100s of lines....
```

Is there anyway to avoid this course of action...if xyz site do funcA, if xyz site do funcB.

I want to use this as a real world lesson to learn some advance structuring of my python code.
So please feel free to guide me towards something fundamental to Python or programming in general.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a dispatch dictionary mapping domain to function:

```
def default_handler(parsed_url):
    pass

def youtube_handler(parsed_url):
    pass

def hulu_handler(parsed_url):
    pass

handlers = {
    'www.youtube.com': youtube_handler,
    'hulu.com':        hulu_handler,
}

handler = handlers.get(urlParsed.netloc, default_handler)
handler(urlParsed)
```

Python functions are first-class objects and can be stored as values in a dictionary just like any other object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `dict`

```
myDict = {"www.youtube.com": youtube, "hulu.com": hulu}

...
...

if urlParsed.netloc in myDict:
    myDict[urlParsed.netloc]()
else:
    print "Unknown URL"
```